# Is there any way to prioritise a window in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

Let's say you have quite a few windows into a process of registering a person's data. You then have a confirmation window at the end that needs to be closed before doing anything else (the window should either be closed by pressing 'Submit' or 'Cancelled'). Is there a way how to do this in tkinter python? The only example I could find to actually give a visual of what I mean is in the properties of a file (https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpHO7.jpg)

Comment: You can use root.withdraw method to close the window, call this method inside bith submit and cancel functions

Comment: Isn't that how to hide it? I want to prioritise the confirmation window.
Imagine you have a window with entrys which you will write to a file and you want to make a confirmation window. The user should not be allowed to move or interact at all with the entrys window unless they have pressed 'Submit' or 'Cancel' on the confirmation window.

Look at the imgur link

Comment: `Toplevel` widgets have `lift()`, `lower()`, and `tkraise()` methods that may allow you to do what you want.

Comment: Also see the ***Stacking Order*** section of this [Tkdocs Tutorial](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/index.html) on [Windows and Dialogs](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/windows.html).